# How to implement NameNode Highly Available in hadoop 1.1.*

Tags: hadoop, high-availability

Does hadoop 1.1.2 supports NN HA ? Because now I am using hbase 0.94.8 which based on hadoop 1.1.2.

Someone can give me some suggestion?  Thanks very much.

Comment: -1 for not checking the release notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDFS HA is in the 2x release and not in the 1X release of Hadoop.